# ListView not scrolling in NestedScrollView (fragment)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-xml

I can't scroll in the listView in NestedScrollView (fragment)

Attempted code:

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:fillViewport="true" /> and <View android:nestedScrollingEnabled = "true" />
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="50px">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="244dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Recherche statistique des pays "
                android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_view">

            </View>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="ÉVOLUTION DU CORONAVIRUS COVID-19 "
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textSize="18dp" />




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/cher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="Statistiques"
                android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="#7a8b8b8b"></View>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadin"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="250" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:divider="#ffffff"></ListView>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lst1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="446dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Nombre total de cas"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tot1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l1"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Nouveaux  cas"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/casN1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l2"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Total des décès"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dead1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l3"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Nouvelles  morts"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Ndead1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l4"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Total récupéré"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Totrec1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l5"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Cas active"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/act1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l6"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Cas critique"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cri1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l7"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="Nombre total de cas / 1M habitants"
                        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tot1m1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="29dp" />


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/l8"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:indeterminate="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>




            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I know I shouldn't use ListView in NestedScrollView, but I have no other option for now

Hope someone can help !

Comment: Start by using RecyclerView, nobody uses ListView since 2014.  Also, can you make the layout file more concise, keeping only what's relevant to the question.

Comment: @Nicolas i'll next time, for RecyclerView, i need to change all java codes also ?

Comment: @Nicolas it's linked with many java codes